# selecting element with id but without document object (in javascript)

Tags: javascript

I mean instead of doing `document.getElmentById('btn1')` I'm just doing this:

```js
btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert("btn1 clicked");
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn1">button</button>
```

How is this code working just fine?

Comment: Instead of having to use "hacks" (formatting arbitrary text as code) to be able to post your question, why don't you include your simple example directly in the question itself instead of jsFiddle? See my edit.